# Global field duplicated

Tags: craft3, globals, multi-site

I have two sites. Everytime I add global field content (slogan for example) it adds the same to the second site, and vice-versa. Anyone has any idea how to stop that?

Comment: Field Layouts are attached to elements directly not on sites. So you can not change the field layout based on the site per default, you would have to create a plugin, would that be a solution for you?

Comment: What I want to change is the content not the layout. My problem is the inverse of this:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/globals.html#global-sets-with-multiple-sites

"you can set the values in those sets on a per site basis, even leaving some fields blank, if desired."

That's not happening, it inserts what i wrote into both sites. I even confirmed on the database: site id 1 and site id 2 both have the same global content

Comment: Are your fields translatable for each site? If not you should change the field setting

Comment: Ok, translatable for each site. Now each site has its own content. Sorry, i see translatable i think languages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the content for each site individually you need to set the field settings accordingly to "translatable for each site"

Otherwise the content for each site will be the same